# Premiere Custom Dip To Black Transition

Tags: premiere, transitions

I would like to use a simple transition throughout a project in a large number of places.

The default Dip to Black transition gets me almost there, with one missing feature - there appears to be no way alter the duration of the out and in phases - I can set the duration of the transition, but what I need to do is to control the speeds individually. What I need is:

Clip 1 fades to black in 8 frames.
Clip 2 fades up from black in 16 frames.

So given that the included Dip To Black doesn't offer this kind of control, what are my options?

Obviously I could individually set opacity with keyframes for every single clip, but given the number of places I need this transition, this seems like a great deal more work than using a transition (that i could copy/paste) would be.

As an added complication, I will be round tripping to Resolve for grading, so anything too non-standard will no doubt cause issues.

Answer (score 2):

This is a surprisingly tricky question, as Premiere doesn't let you edit transitions like, say FCP does.

One way of doing it is to use presets:

First create a preset for your fade in. Set two opacity keyframes for your fade-in then in the **Effect Control** panel right click on the **Opacity** effect and choose **Save Preset**:

[image]

call it fade-in or whatever and choose **Anchor to In Point**, so that it will apply it to the start of the clip.

[image]

Then on a fresh clip with no keyframes do the same for your fade out, choosing **Anchor to Out Point** in the dialog.

Now you can apply both your presets to your clips to create your fade out / in, and the good thing is that the presets will add new keyframes without deleting the existing ones, so the fade in won't overwrite the keyframes of the fade out. **Tip**: you can select both presets in the Presets folder in your effects window by holding down <kbd>Command / Control</kbd>, then you can drag them both to a clip at the same time.